# Bulk insert instead of loop in PLSQL?

Tags: plsql, cursor, oracle11g, bulkinsert

I am trying to solve this piece of code with a bulk insert or something else more effective but I am out of ideas. How would you approach this problem. Instead of looping so many times i would like to do it more effective in few calls. Please let me know how you would do? With code if possible! Thanx

```
LOOP
-- Fetch a row
IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(cursor_handle) > 0 THEN
    DBMS_SQL.column_value(cursor_handle, 9, cont_id); 
    DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(cursor_handle, 3, proj_nr);  
    HTP.BOLD('ContractID: ' || cont_id || ' ProjectNR: ' ||  proj_nr);
    HTP.BR;
ELSE
    EXIT;
END IF;

-- delete the old list before saving a new one
IF sek_nr = 1 THEN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DELETE FROM W_Contracts WHERE user_id = :n' USING CURRENTUSER;
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Insert into W_Contracts values(''' || currentUser || ''', '
                   || sek_nr || ', sysdate, ' || cont_id || ', '''
                   || proj_nr || ''')';

sek_nr := sek_nr + 1;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, it's not clear to me why you're using dynamic SQL rather than static SQL.

```
IF sek_nr = 1 
THEN
  DELETE FROM w_contracts
   WHERE user_id = currentUser;
END IF;

INSERT INTO w_contracts( <<list of columns>> )
  VALUES( currentUser, sek_nr, sysdate, cont_id, proj_nr );
```

Next, it's not obvious to me why you're potentially doing a `DELETE` and then an `INSERT` if the `SEK_NR` is 1.  It would likely be more efficient to do an `UPDATE` in that case.  And once you're doing an `UPDATE` and an `INSERT`, you can simplify that into a single `MERGE` statement.

Next, if you use the [`DEFINE_ARRAY` method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm#i1025685) in `DBMS_SQL`, you can do bulk fetches of data from your cursor.  Of course, without seeing your cursor definition, I would be suspicious that it too was using dynamic SQL unnecessarily and that you could use a much simpler approach.

Comment: Thanx for your answer Justin. You are right about the dynamic sql part. I'll try to explain the rest of the code. Since there is no guarantee that sek_nr = 1 I check this every time in my loop which is not the best solution i guess. But if sek_nr is 1 I want to delete a entry from w_contracts table only once. Thereafter I continue with my insert which I know is a performance issue. It would be more effective to solve this in some other way, like bulk insert or something else. Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this ? Thanks for your help!